# MySQL index order with joins

Tags: mysql, join, indexing

I'm trying to get the column order in our indexes set correctly and haven't seen a direct answer on this.  If we have a query like the following

```
SELECT ... all the things ... 
FROM tb_contact 
inner join tb_contact_association on tb_contact.id = tb_contact_association.attached_id 
where tb_contact_association.contact_id = '498' 
order by ...
```

We're looking at a pivot table, tb_contact_association on this join.  And this table is never really queried without looking at both attached_id (on the join) and contact_id (the where).

When creating an index for tb_contact_association, should the index cover both "attached_id,contact_id" in that order? With the joined on first, then the where? Or the other way around? Or each of them individually?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have question about query optimisation and indexes then generally you have to provide the explain for said query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the ordering of fields in an index doesn't matter, **IF** you use the appropriate fields.

e.g. for a query like:

```
SELECT .. WHERE f1 = 'a' AND f2 = 'b' AND f3 = 'c'

INDEX(f3, f2, f1) - index can be used
INDEX(f1, f3, f1) - can be used
INDEX(f1, f2, f3) - can be used
INDEX(f1, f3) - completely usable
INDEX(f3, f1) - completely usable
INDEX(f4, f1) - cannot be used - no 'f4' field in the where clause
INDEX(f1, f4) - can be used, because 'f1' is in the where clause, but f4
    component will be ignored
```

The actual ordering of the `WHERE` clause doesn't matter. `WHERE f1 = 'a' AND f2 = 'b'` v.s. `WHERE f2 = 'b' AND f1 = 'a'` are both indentical as far as the query compiler/optimizer are concerned.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, both fields should have an index. However in this query, only contact_id needs an index, Nathan's answer explains why in more details.

The optimal index for your specific query would be (contact_id, attached_id).

Comment: Highest cardinality first in a composite index is a common rule of thumb, but it doesn't apply here*.  Only one of the fields appears in the WHERE clause, so it must come first for the index to be used. The other field in the index is only valuable in that it allows mysql to read all necessary data from the index, without accessing the data table.  *In fact, even when it does apply - when both columns in the index will always appear in the WHERE clause, it may not provide any actual value putting the higher cardinality column first - but at least in that case it can't hurt.

Comment: *In fact, even when it does apply - when both columns in the index will always appear in the WHERE clause, it may not provide any actual value putting the higher cardinality column first" Why not? Could you elaborate on that part? Of course there's always exceptions but generally speaking on a typical dataset using the highest cardinality field first should be faster on average no?

Comment: In theory perhaps -- I have certainly read that rule of thumb elsewhere.  And it makes logical sense.  However, I have yet to see a measurable difference in testing.  All else being equal, if I knew I was going to have only WHERE clauses containing both values in a composite index, and I knew they would be 'equals' references (not ranges), I would put the higher cardinality column first -- but it's very rare that all those conditions are met.  Usually, like in this question, there is an overriding factor that makes the choice for you. (Or it's necessary to have indexes both ways.)

Answer (score 1):

The indexes needed depend on which direction the join will run.  You can determine this by running an EXPLAIN on your select statement.  In this case though, since your WHERE clause is filtering on the tb_contact_association table, the optimizer will most likely start with this table and join into the tb_contact table.

The exception would be if tb_contact is small (few rows) compared to tb_contact_association.  To see why this is the case, consider an extreme example.  If tb_contact is only one row long, it's obviously going to be faster to start from that row, join into the corresponding row in the tb_contact_association table, and test its value for contact_id, rather than go through the whole larger tb_contact_association table looking for contact_id=498 (even with an index), and then joining back to the tb_contact table.

But, for any normal tables, the query above would start with tb_contact_association.  For a join, you need an index on the column you're joining *to*.  In this case, that's tb_contact.id.  You'll also want an index to help your WHERE clause, ie on tb_contact_association.contact_id.

You don't actually need an index on tb_contact_association.attached_id for this particular query, as long as the join always goes in the direction we expect.  A composite index on (contact_id, attached_id) (in that order) in tb_contact_association should be a slight help, because it will allow all necessary info for that table to be pulled directly from the index, saving a read from the data table for each row.  (With this index added, you should see "using index" in the extra section of the query EXPLAIN.)  The contact_id column is used for the WHERE clause, just as with a single index on that column, but with the composite index, it can then just read attached_id straight from the index, rather than from the table.

Comment: Note though that you need to consider all queries you'll be running on these tables.  If it's possible some will be better joining in the opposite direction, then it may be useful to have an index on attached_id.